# Flex Image control can't handle URLs with special characters

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash

I'm building a Flex application where users can enter a URL to an image on the Internet and then have flash load the image that the URL points to. This works fine for URLs with no special characters (by either setting the `source` property or calling `load()` on `Image`). However, when a URL is submitted that has special characters which have already been escaped, i.e. in most cases simply copied directly from the URL bar in a browser, `URLRequest` escapes the percent signs again with '%25', which makes the URL invalid and the server returns an error. Pasting the same URL in a browser loads the image just fine though. I've tried `decodeURI()` on the URL, but that ignores a large set of characters, so I tried `decodeURIComponent()`, and that decodes everything correctly, but when `URLRequest` goes to re-encode it, it ignores the now-decoded special characters and doesn't escape them, so in this case the URL is not valid, because it still has unsafe characters in it and fails. So, how can I send `URLRequest` something with special characters in it (encoded or unencoded) and have it actually work? Really, I wish it didn't do anything with my URL and let me determine if it's valid or not, but it's embedded in the Flash Player globals swc and is therefore the closed-source piece of flash and I can't see the source code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is basically what I'm doing:

```
var image:Image = new Image();
image.source = textInput.text;
```

And the URL I've been testing with is from Getty images:

http://cache2.asset-cache.net/gc/sb10064464f-001-dog-looking-up-close-up-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=BRDT%2firX5%2bLh54FjE4ekKh%2bjEirx6jSgMBJOgVxvtKL5ngFuzD9P5u%2bPvlXK4QAMaEHcwY6NrdJUQFip1%2fKXAA%3d%3d

If you step through the code, in the `loadContent()` function in `SWFLoader` (which `Image` extends), after `requestedURL` is created from a `new URLRequest`, the `url` property on the `URLRequest` object has all percent signs escaped (again) with '%25', producing the following URL (which will return a 500 error from Getty):

http://cache2.asset-cache.net/gc/sb10064464f-001-dog-looking-up-close-up-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=BRDT%252firX5%252bLh54FjE4ekKh%252bjEirx6jSgMBJOgVxvtKL5ngFuzD9P5u%252bPvlXK4QAMaEHcwY6NrdJUQFip1%252fKXAA%253d%253d

**Update**

- I forgot to mention that I'm running Flex SDK 4.1, and the `Image` is `mx.controls.Image`
- Based on wvxvw's suggestion, I tried `unescape()` with the same result as using `decodeURIComponent()`
- I also tried calling `encodeURI()` on the URL after decoding with `decodeURIComponent()`, but of course it ignores many of the unsafe characters that are in the decoded URL and doesn't re-encode them. `URLRequest` does the same, so the URL called in the end isn't encoded and therefore fails.
- Interestingly too, when I tried calling `encodeURIComponent()` on the URL and re-encoding it before passing it in, `URLRequest` did not re-encode the percents, presumably because they're already '%25'?
- In the end, it seems to only look for '%' signs and simply replaces them with '%25' (if they aren't followed already by '25') and then ignores the other unsafe characters. Why would it do that? And why hasn't anyone else run into this problem before?

Comment: I tried unescape() with the same result. It decodes it correctly, but then URLRequest doesn't re-encode the unsafe characters

Comment: I guess I should be updating the original question as well, right? This is my first question on the S-O-Flow

Comment: no, it's actually not going through the browser, it's making a plain old `URLRequest` to a URL I'm passing it in, so if I send it a URL with a '/' in it (an unsafe character that makes the URL invalid), it doesn't encode that with '%2f', so the HTTP request fails.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it for me! You're absolutely right and after some more digging, I found that it's happening in the `OSToPlayerURI()` function in `SWFLoader`. It calls `decodeURI()` followed immediately by `encodeURI()`, which is encoding '%'

Comment: Oh and the "/" character is not allowed in the querystring. It's a reserved character and must be encoded when occurring in a key or value in the querystring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For images loaded from URLs with potentially unsafe characters, you must use `Loader` or `URLLoader` and load them manually, which avoids `SWFLoader` and the `OSToPlayerURI()` function.